# Remove method using linq

Tags: linq, nhibernate

How do I implement the following method (preferably without fetching the items from the database first):

```
public void Remove(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> query)
{
  _session.XXXXXXX
}
```

It's for my repository class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that's not currently possible, as Linq in NH is only supported for data-retrieving queries, not updates.

An alternative is using HQL updates: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#batch-direct

The end result is the same: HQL queries are type-safe and compiled (by NHibernate)